# TSQL: use global ##temp for multiple runs of same sp, how to reuse?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to run same sp with 100 diff @params once a month which reference data which is hard to get (view runs 2 min, and I need only 2% subset from this view). I want to create some ##temp table so then my sp in all instances will refer to it. How people do this on tsql arena?
Can I include:
`If exist then do nothing` 
in the top of sp code, so it will run only once? and then delete table in separate clean job.   or do some ##temp tables, I"m bit new to this . not sure will ## global temp table will work. ALso do I need to go with some special Isolation Level (Serial?) to do this.

Tx for help.
Mario

Answer (score 1):

If the procedure only runs once a month, and view takes its time to run (expensive query) why not just create a table (maybe create some indexes too , to aid the following queries) and then finally create another procedure to populate that table each time you execute your original procedure.

```
-- Create a holding table 

SELECT * INTO Holding_Table
FROM Your_View
WHERE 1 = 2




-- Procedure to populate data into that holding table

CREATE PROCEDURE populate_data 
AS
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE Holding_Table  

  INSERT INTO Holding_Table
  SELECT * FROM Your_View

END
```

Now call this procedure from your existing procedure to populate the data and carry on working with the holding table as usual ...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE your_existing_Proc 
AS
BEGIN
   Exec populate_data 
.....  rest of the procedure definition
```

Comment: This is great advice, just create normal tables and index appropriately

Comment: Thanks ALL, I still want do more savings, in my case `HOLDING_TABLE` is the same for all 100 runs and need to be updated once a month, so I want to create it just once. `SELECT * from Your_View` is the killer.  Why I need to call it each time from  `your_existing_Proc` each time? I can just do condition if exists then go forward, sorry If I still missing something.. Best.M